Why does this FastAPI Endpoint return an empty string for optional email parameter?
I'm working on a FastAPI application with the following endpoint designed to handle file uploads and an optional email parameter to return a grade:
from fastapi import FastAPI, UploadFile, Response
from typing import Optional

app = FastAPI()

@app.post('/grades')
async def request_legacy(
    response: Response,
    grade_file: UploadFile,
    grade_email: Optional[str] = None
):
    # Doing other stuff here unrelated, but eventually do:
    print(f"Grade email: {grade_email}")
    return {"Group": grade_email or ""}

I am querying this endpoint using the requests library as follows:
import requests

api_url = "http://localhost:8000/grades"

with open("request.py", "rb") as f:
    files = {'grade_file': f}
    data = {'grade_email': "test@mail.com"}
    
    response = requests.post(api_url, files=files, data=data, verify=False)

print(response.json())

However, every time I make this request, I receive an empty string for the grade_email in the return body. I'm not sure why this optional parameter isn't being read correctly by my endpoint.
I've tried sending it several ways, but I don't see how this would work. I've checked the logs for any errors and ensured im using the correct key for the dictionary in data.

Import Form from fastapi and add this instead
´
grade_email: Optional[str] = Form(None)
´
When you are sending both files and data using requests, FastAPI may not recognize grade_email correctly, especially when using UploadFile.
